# how to judge sql performance through these two explain?

Tags: mysql, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

If I give you 2 explain results from MySQL,how do you know which query is better?

the first sql explain

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sbtest2
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 700100
        Extra: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and the second sql explain

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 100
        Extra: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: a
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: b.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: sbtest2
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 700100
        Extra: Using index
3 rows in set (1.46 sec)
```

I think I will choose the first query because there are "a lot of" things to do in the second explain,but actually the second query is much faster than the first query , so my question is if I don't see the response time,how to judge their performance through explain ?

the first query's Duration: 4.43704325

```
select * from sbtest.sbtest2 
order by id 
limit 700000,100;
```

after restart mysql to clean cache and the second one is Duration: 2.08889400 (faster)

```
select * from sbtest.sbtest2 a
inner join 
(select id from sbtest.sbtest2  order by id limit 700000,100 ) as b
on a.id=b.id;
```

table structure is above

```
mysql> show create table sbtest.sbtest1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: sbtest1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `sbtest1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `k` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c` char(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pad` char(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `k` (`k`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5265529 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 MAX_ROWS=1000000
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

can anybody help me ?

---

additional

```
mysql> explain select id from sbtest.sbtest2  order by id limit 700000,100\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sbtest2
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 700100
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

time is 4.28456200

Answer (score 1):

`EXPLAIN` estimates row counts, often poorly.  Even so, the counts do not reflect how much stuff is hauled around.  If it is only `id`, that is not much.  If it is all of `*` (as in `SELECT *`), that is a lot more.  This is especially the case when it has to reach into the data to get all the columns.

`Using index` means that it is cruising through the index BTree.  Without that phrase, it is bouncing between the index BTree and the data BTree (using the `PRIMARY KEY`).  This bouncing is costly, and that cost is not adequately reflected in `EXPLAIN`.

`Using index` may be your only clue, but it cannot be trusted.  Sometimes it helps only a little, sometimes it helps a lot.

`limit 700000,100` is an awful thing to do.  It must fetch 700100 rows (of just `id` or of `*`) but throw away nearly all of them.

Your complex query is the trick to make `OFFSET` perform somewhat better.  There is no way to say skip over 700000 rows without looking at them (which is what everyone wants).

Other notes:

Don't use `CHAR`, especially not with `utf8`; switch to `VARCHAR`.  `char(120)` consumes a fixed 360 bytes, regardless of the text.  The unnecessary bulk is a performance issue, especially if the table is bigger than can be cached.

[More discussion of `OFFSET`](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).